# How to print packet info of a specific IP address in netfilter using C?

Tags: c, hook, netfilter

I'm using this code to print some packet info about "all" received and sent packets from all IP addresses. How do I only print packet info of a specific IP address?

this is part of the code:

```
{
struct ethhdr *eth;
struct iphdr *ip_header;

eth = (struct ethhdr*)skb_mac_header(skb);
ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

if (HOST_IP_ADDR == ip_header->saddr)
      return NF_ACCEPT;

printk("NF_IP_LOCAL_IN hook:\n");
printk("src mac %pM, dst mac %pM\n", eth->h_source, eth->h_dest);
printk("src IP addr:=%pI4\n", &ip_header->saddr);
return NF_ACCEPT;
}
```

Comment: Something along the line of `if (the ip address == the ip address you want) {print the stuff}`?

Comment: I tried this option and also I used strcmp, both of them gives errors.

Comment: `if (HOST_IP_ADDR == ip_header->saddr)` looks like an IP address comparison to me. So you know how to compare IP addresses.

Comment: I would like to capture packet info for specific address, my VM has around 10 IP. I assign those IPs statically and I need a way to compare

Answer (score 0):

If you have HOST_IP_ADDR defined as a string you can use `in_aton()` around the ip address you want to match against

```
ip_header = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);

if (in_aton("192.168.1.1") == ip_header->saddr)
{
    // matches 192.168.1.1
}
```